# How to add .click to a dropdown button using jquery instead of javascript?

Tags: jquery

Hi so the current code that I have (but don't understand the first 4 lines of it) is below. How can I use Jquery in the first 4 lines instead as I am required to use Jquery? Thank you

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('#list li')
links.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let numberOfChoices = event.target.innerText
    $('dropdownMenu').innerHTML = `${numberOfChoices}<span class="caret"></span>`

    if (numberOfChoices === "2") {
      $("#img3").addClass("invisible")
    }
    if (numberOfChoices === "3") {
      $("#img4).addClass("invisible");
      $("#img3).removeClass("invisible")
    }
    if (numberOfChoices === "4") {
      $("#img3").removeClass("invisible");
    }
    chosen = "yes"
  })
})
```

And the html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        2
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul id="list" class="parent dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li class= "child"><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li  class= "child"><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li  class= "child"><a href="#">4</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll break down the four lines to explain what they do an how they convert:

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('#list li')
```

This selects all the `li` elements inside a element with id list into a variable `links`.

```
links.forEach((el) => {
```

Looping through each `li` element and passing them into the loop as `el` per element per loop.

```
el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
```

For each elemment list to when the user clicks.

```
let numberOfChoices = event.target.innerText
```

Taking the text of each element (the number) and assigning them to a variable `numberOfChoices`

**In jQuery**

These four lines in jQuery can be converted to :

```
$('#links li').each(function() {
  const $el = $(this);
  $el.click(function(e) {
    const numberOfChoices = $el.text();
```

With the breakdown being

```
$('#links li').each(function() {
```

This does the exact same thing as the first two lines in vanilla js where I've selected all the elements and looping through them.

```
const $el = $(this);
```

This line is optional, you can continue to use `$(this)` but note the scope of `this` will change if you have nested functions so best to assign it to a variable.

```
$el.click(function(e) {
```

Binding click to the element.

```
const numberOfChoices = $el.text();
```

Storing the text of the element in a variable `numberOfChoices`.

```js
$('#list li').each(function() {
  const $el = $(this);
  $el.click(function(e) {
    const numberOfChoices = $el.text();

    $('#dropdownMenu').html(`${numberOfChoices}<span class="caret"></span>`);

    if (numberOfChoices === "2") {
      $("#img3").addClass("invisible");
    }
    if (numberOfChoices === "3") {
      $("#img4").addClass("invisible");
      $("#img3").removeClass("invisible");
    }
    if (numberOfChoices === "4") {
      $("#img3").removeClass("invisible");
    }
    chosen = "yes";
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        2
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul id="list" class="parent dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li class= "child"><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li  class= "child"><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li  class= "child"><a href="#">4</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery there is no need for the `.each()` call as each selected element will be assigned the click event anyway.

```js
$('#list li').click(function(e) {
  const numberOfChoices =$(this).text(); 
  $('#dropdownMenu').html(numberOfChoices);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        2
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul id="list" class="parent dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li class= "child"><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li  class= "child"><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li  class= "child"><a href="#">4</a></li>
      </ul>
```